# Is there a based software to capture videos/images from multiple webcams?

Tags: video-capture

Is there a (possibly free) software that allows us to capture videos/images simultanously at low frequency (1 image/frame per second) from multiple (8-10) webcams (either LifeCam HD 3000 or Depstech 2.0 Mpx CMOS HD USB Endoskop) on a Windows 10 based tablet?

FYI: We try to assess the frequency of bees visiting squash flowers. Video capturing would us allow to make as many observations as possible during floresecence. NO spying or other weird things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the low frequency, but [iSpy](https://www.ispyconnect.com/default.aspx) runs on windows 10 and captures video and image from multiple devices.

Comment: Yes, it does, but only from different camera models (with different drivers), not from multiple cameras of the same model...